# Time series correlation issue

Tags: r, time-series, correlation

I have time bins (every 0.5 million years) with measures of two variables (Diversity and CO2).

```
>head(matrix)

  Age       Diversity    CO2
1 0.0       0.4971946 1.0000000
2 0.5       0.4039132 0.9982684
3 1.0       0.4062398 0.9957440
4 1.5       0.4093916 0.9950622
5 2.0       0.4128504 1.0039857
6 2.5       0.4138772 1.0311683
. ..            .        .

>plot(matrix$Diversity ~ matrix$CO2, xlab = "CO2", ylab="Diversity")
```

[image]

Although correlation exists

```
>cor(matrix$Extinction_Rate,matrix$CO2)
[1] -0.8303699
```

the resulted plot is pretty odd (temporal autocorrelation?). I was thinking that maybe resampling (bootstrap) several times each of the x,y rows of the matrix might help, but I am not sure about that. Any ideas?

Comment: It could make sense to examine changes in diversity against changes in CO2 as there appears to be high persistence / only gradual development, but even this relationship will not be linear. (This is assuming the path seen in the graph has nearby points that are indeed the nearby points in time.)

Answer (score 0):

Your pearson's correlation captures only linear dependence between your two variables, while your data clearly exhibit highly-nonlinear dependence structure. Since I guess you are mostly interested in the evolution of the dependence, it may be good to connect successive measurements with a line so that the reader can follow the path of evolution along the years.

From a quick look it seems like the underlying system governing the relation between the two variables change on a number of instances. For example, in the first portion of your data there is some linear relationship wich then quickly changes to a non-linear dependence, changes direction and then becomes independent.